# Stripe : list all charges with PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I tried to list all charges of my Stripe account to get a list of the statement_descriptor (my products) but I there is an error which says cannot find charge...

```
<?php
$off = 0;
$has_more = True;
$listeProducts = array();
ini_set('max_execution_time', 2000);
while($has_more){
    $req = \Stripe\Charge::all(array("limit" => 100, "starting_after" => $off));
    $res = json_decode($req->__toJSON(), true);

    foreach($res["data"] as &$prodUni){
        array_push($listeProducts, $prodUni["statement_descriptor"]);
    }

    $has_more = $res["has_more"];
    $off += 100;
}
$_SESSION["products"] = $listeProducts;
```

Here is the error message :

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest' with message 'No such charge: 0' in C:\wamp64\www\...\stripe-php-5.1.3\lib\ApiRequestor.php:124 from API request '...' in C:\wamp64\www\...\stripe-php-5.1.3\lib\ApiRequestor.php on line 124
```

I cant put "offset" because deprecated and it does same thing with ending before.

**The issue is that I put 0 but charge ID is required.... I don't want to put charge ID there... I need to do like if I had offset**

Comment: BTW: do not use short tags (`<?`) - it can be turned off and then your code is exposed nicely.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I use <?php echo 'hello'; ?> is that correct ?

Comment: better. I also edited your question to not feature short tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`starting_after` takes an object - ideally the last object in the previous fetched result.

See https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php#list_charges-starting_after

Comment: Yes thanks, I have edited and put in bold that I need to do it with offset but if there is an alternative it is cool... So how to do ? What is the equivalent for offset=0 ? because I do then offset=100, offset=200 etc with a while($has_more)

Comment: offset is not used anymore. You will get your first list of objects, make a note of the last one, then run your query again. So, in your while loop, just get the last object in each set of results (100) and pass that as the `starting_after`, it is essentially an offset - you are asking for items after that one.

Comment: Thanks a lot, and how to beging ? What can I put in the first 'starting_after' ? I don't want to miss the first charge.

Comment: The object you'll need to pass is the last `$res` in each while loop... You are foreach-ing through them, make a note and keep the last one, then pass that to your `starting_after`. (i'm trying so hard not to write the code for you - you can do it! :))

Comment: Yes thanks I understood that but if I pass the last $res in the first loop that's not possible, this is the first loop ! So there is no last $res for the first loop.. **So what is the first object to pass ?**

Comment: Have you thought about getting the first 100 before you check for `has_more`? Maybe you could get a 100, _then_ while(has_more)....

Comment: Oh yeah you right great thanks a lot. I have added : *$lastId = $res["data"]["99"]["id"];*

Answer (score 0):

Fist part of answer to the question is getting the first 100 before you check for has_more.

But after that, I cannt retrieve the first charge, dont forget that when we retrieve with Stripe API the list is in the REVERSE ORDER !!! So I have to get the last or the firt ?? How can I correct my code pease ?
And is this line correct ? $lastId = $res["data"]["99"]["id"];

```html
    <?php
    $req = \Stripe\Charge::all(array("limit" => 1, "starting_after" => $lastId));
    $res = json_decode($req->__toJSON(), true);
    $lastId = $res["data"]["99"]["id"];
    $has_more = True;

    while($has_more){

        foreach($res["data"] as &$chargeUni){
            //...
        }
        
        $req = \Stripe\Charge::all(array("limit" => 10, "starting_after" => $lastId));
        $res = json_decode($req->__toJSON(), true);

        $has_more = False;//$res["has_more"];
        $lastId = $res["data"]["99"]["id"];
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The Stripe API offers an **[autopagination](https://stripe.com/docs/api/pagination) feature**:

> This feature easily handles fetching large lists of resources without having to manually paginate results and perform subsequent requests.

Adapted from the docs, this will do the trick nicely (and is much easier to read):

```php
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_…");

/**
 * Automatically go through _all_ charges, fetching the data in chunks/pages of
 * 100 results.
 */
$charges = \Stripe\Charge::all(["limit" => 100]);
foreach ($charges->autoPagingIterator() as $charge) {
  // Do something with $charge
}
```

Comment: Good answer, besides `autoPagingIterator()` there are other methods to use such as `getIterator()` instead of directly access `['data']`  array key, `count()`, `isEmpty()`. See more at **[lib/Collection.php](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/03765fcf15617064c71d6d9188e49d72519f2278/lib/Collection.php#L173)**, **[lib/SearchResult.php](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/03765fcf15617064c71d6d9188e49d72519f2278/lib/SearchResult.php#L132)**